# why a simple android app takes large memory

Tags: android, performance, memory

I am developing an android application which has many drawable png images and it has one form with 10 form fields but when the app is run it takes up to 200 mb of memory.

the app has splash screen and four main activities.
and i am using nexus 10.1 inch device
in the logcat i have seen:
Grow heap (frag case) to 43.800MB for 7166416-byte allocation

i have moved all the images to drawable-xdpi
and i used System.gc(); 
but the memory problem still occurs can any one help me on this

Comment: "when the app is run it takes up to 200 mb of memory" -- that is extremely unlikely. You are welcome to use `procstats` or the equivalent to get a better idea of how much memory your process takes, and you are welcome to use MAT to determine how much heap space you are using and what that heap space is being used for.

Comment: As @CommonsWare states, check your memory. Vogella wrote a rather neat tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html

Comment: Are you using BIG images? Or MANY?

Comment: @Der Golem I used large images for the splash and for the buttons the images are 130 in numbers

Comment: OK, then ask us why your app is likely to generate OOMs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here

1: You can reduce the "quality" of your images without really affecting how they look in the 
   application. You can use "gimp" or a similar tool to achieve this for the images stored in 
    your resource directories.

2: When you read them in use BitmapFactory.Options, Using inSampleSize will greatly reduce your memory footprint because the image will be scaled down when BitmapFactory.decodeStream is called.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   Options.inSampleSize = 2;
   Options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

3: Make sure to call recycle() on your bitmaps when you are done with them.